Error messages when trying to build a git modules
I am trying to build the git repo of: https://github.com/felk/dolphin, and I am getting errors when I try to build it using the .sln file and in VisualStudio2022(latest version), and am getting multiple errors:
36>C:\Users\License_Name\Downloads\dolphin modded 2\dolphin\Source\Core\Scripting\Python\Modules\controllermodule.h(7,1): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory
36>  #include <Python.h>
  ^ (compiling source file '/Python/Modules/controllermodule.cpp')

the error above (of "no such file or directory")was returned 11 times
another error I got was:
38>d:\Source\Core\Core\PowerPC\JitArm64\Jit.cpp(429,1): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error 38>d:\Source\Core\Core\PowerPC\JitArm64\Jit.cpp(429,1): warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'host_address_after_return' used 38>d:\Source\Core\Core\PowerPC\JitArm64\Jit.cpp(429,1): warning C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'host_address_after_return' used

and also:
41>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(452,5): error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Debug|Win32. (this error was returned 125 times).
The end output from building is ========== Rebuild: 36 succeeded, 7 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========. Does anyone know why I am getting these errors, or how to fix them so that the file works properly?

As of the error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory — the include directory is in Externals/python/x64/include which is a submodule Externals/python. Try pointing VSCode to it.

That has made it work, thank you so much for your help!

Is there a way to mark your comment as the answer(so that people know that this is solved)?

No, I just converted the comment to an answer. But I think it'd be better if you write a more elaborate answer explaining what exactly to configure in VSCode.

It just kind of worked after opening the files- I don't really know how or why

As of the error "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory" — the include directory is in Externals/python/x64/include which is a submodule Externals/python. Point VSCode to the directory.
