Building Git submodules not working properly when opening it with visual studio code
I am using visual studio code 2022, and have cloned the git repo https://github.com/felk/dolphin in terminal(I made sure to clone it correctly), and am getting the error of "The "dolphin" repository has 18 submodules which won't be opened automatically. You can still open each one individually by opening a file within." when I open it in visual studio code. This means that the file isn't building properly. Does anyone know how to fix it so that the submodules are opened, and how do I tell which submodules aren't being opened?

I'd like to point that this is a continuation from https://stackoverflow.com/q/78255525/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/78261948/7976758

are you sure that that's what's causing build failures? I'd have thought that your build tools (whether or not they are being driven by a VS Code extension) wouldn't care what VS Code's machinery is doing...

It decided to start working after opening them individually since I managed to find them

So yes, I think that was what was causing build failures @starball

I Have just managed to fix the issue by going in and opening all the files - I found that to do that you have to build it in Visual-Studio Code(Not Visual Studio), and then it will flag up the submodules that aren't being opened. Then you go into each submodule and double click(open) the file that is named "ReadMe" for that submodule. Do this for all submodules that are flagged/have a blue dot next to them, and then it should work.

thx man, saved me a lot of time
